# How to pause/resume upload file to server in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload

I want to pause/resume upload file to server in iOS. Is it possible ?

Comment: The answer is yes, it can be done,

but ONLY if both server and iOS applications are fine with it

what is the method you wan't to use to upload the file?

Comment: use AFNetworking for the same. It will help u in achieving the save with very less efforts

Comment: AFNetworking can pause but not resume. ISSUE https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/887

Comment: I need to config server for pause/resume upload file ?

Comment: This question really isn't answerable in it's current state, @Uglybrd. You don't say if the server receiving the file can handle pausing or resume, or if you have control over the server code.

Comment: this is an example code that i made but not work! https://gist.github.com/uglybrd/6507621

Comment: Please advise me that should do it. LoL

Comment: @Uglybrd do you succeed or find some workaround

Comment: @M.ShuaibImran I uesed http://tus.io